# Reserve selected records in a sql server

Tags: sql-server, records

I could use some advice on how to solve this issue. I have application that connect  to a sql server and fetch some records, when this is done I need to "reserve" those records so that in case another instance of another application connect at the same time that instance will not fetch the same records.

Comment: by reserve, do you mean lock those rows?

Comment: Why do you think you need to lock records at all? Are you trying to implement a quick&dirty checkout functionality perhaps? Don't. You'll eradicate your server's performance and manage to lock the entire system even with just two clients.

Comment: Checkout/reservation/workflow are all *BUSINESS* concerns. Locking and transactions are a low-level *data processing* concern. You'll have to gather requirements and implement the checkout mechanism yourself. For example, how long can a record be checked out? Can an administrator force a checkin? What about "big" records? Why checkout instead of an actual workflow, eg assigning different records to different users?

Comment: Once you know what it is you need to build, you can implement it, eg with views that only return what the current user is allowed to view, stored procedures to handle checkin/checkout etc.

Comment: Just check applications that already allow this, eg task/project management applications like Redmine or any other issue tracking application. **NONE** of them uses data locks to implement checkin/workflow. All use the appropriate schema to assign tasks, check-out/check-in records, etc

Comment: You'll also need to consider tracking/auditing of checkouts. Users *always* want to know the history of a record, or who is working on it at a certain time.

Comment: The reason I asked is that when the application has fetched x number of records it does some tasks locally that take various amount of time. When its done the sql server records are updated depending on some logic on that aplication.

Comment: Explain the actual problem, not the attempted solution. Locks are completely inappropriate for checkouts. They are also inappropriate for use as staging markers, versioning, labelling etc. BTW, pulling data on the client instead of processing on the server is another "unusual" choice. That's what ETL is for

Comment: The problem is this... Application 1 select 10 records and process them locally which take 30 seconds. Just after application 1 has fetched 10 records application 2 connects to the sql server, application 2 can then not retrieve the same 10 records as application 1 did.

Comment: Just add a status field for handling what records are "free" and what are being processed?